# check user permissions for specific file in sharepoint client object model

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, permissions

I want to check if specific user has which permission for specific file or folder of any document library in share point client object model.

Comment: javascript, c#, powershell??

Comment: I want code for c#

Answer (score 1):

SPlistitem has a function DoesuserhavePermission,  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms472022.aspx

try this one,

```
SPList objList = web.GetList(this.NewsItemURL);
SPListItem objListItem = null;

try
{
     objListItem = objList.GetItemById(_intNewsItemID);
 if (!objListItem.DoesUserHavePermissions(web.CurrentUser, SPBasePermissions.ViewListItems))
 {
     _strErrMsg = "Does not have permission";
 }

}

catch (ArgumentException)
{
     objListItem = null;
}
```

Also very good article.
http://melick-rajee.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-check-user-permission-for-web.html